# Why didn't SQLite3 fail when using an invalid datatype

Tags: sqlite

I created a table as in a tutorial on sitepoint.com

```
CREATE TABLE comments ( 
post_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
name TEXT NOT NULL, 
email TEXT NOT NULL, 
website TEXT NULL, 
comment TEXT NOT NULL );
```

Then I tried adding a column

```
ALTER TABLE comments
INSERT COLUMN enabled BOOL
```

Then I realized that there is no `BOOL` type in SQLite. But the entry was added

```
sqlite> .schema comments
CREATE TABLE comments (
post_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
email TEXT NOT NULL,
website TEXT NOT NULL,
comment TEXT NOT NULL , enabled BOOL);
```

Why didn't SQLite oppose?

Comment: BOOL is automatically converted to NUMERIC. That's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname:

> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the column, according to the following rules in the order shown:
>
> 1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned INTEGER affinity.
> 2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity.
> 3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
> 4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> 5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.

Basically, you can use any declared type for column and its affinity will be determined by above rules. Column with `BOOL` declared type will have `NUMERIC` affinity.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [Type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

To make it short sqlite will try to find the most relevant type even if it doesn't match the *official* ones. This is done for compatibility reasons with other databases.